# Calculator that can calculate with units

Tags: windows, gratis, calculator

I'm looking for a calculator

- that can calculate (basic operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` would suffice, more are welcome)
- that can calculate including units (e.g. `2m² + 5000cm²`)
- can convert units (e.g. `m to ft`)
- is gratis
- works on Windows
- starts up quickly and is easy to use

Ideally (but optional)

- is portable

I do not want

- a full-blown mathematics solution like Matlab, Mathematica or similar

Comment: What kind of Windows do you have ?

Comment: @PROBERT: Windows 7 SP1 x64. I used to add that to questions and use the Windows-7 tag, but often it was edited out, so I go with "Windows" since then.

Comment: If you upgrade to Windows 10, there is an app for that and has all kind of different app that use that https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/unit-conversion/9wzdncrfj0pr      Just thought I'd let you know.  and here is another one you probably want to take a look at here http://www.howtogeek.com/136288/the-best-free-programs-and-websites-for-converting-units-and-currency/

Comment: @PROBERT: Both look like it can convert but not calculate (e.g. `(2300m²+5400m²)/2 in ft²`)

Comment: You can do this with Wolfram Alpha.  It has an offline mode but there is a limit on use before you have to start paying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have replaced Phyxcalc with [Qalculate](https://qalculate.github.io/), which has more features and a UI that is a bit more self-explanatory.

- it's [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), GPL 2 license
- it works on Windows 10 x64 1909 (official docs say it works from Vista)
- startup time is ~ 2 seconds
- download size is 51 MB, which is not exactly small. The largest thing about it is a 23 MB Unicode library (`libicudt`) which gives the nice graphical output.
- the 32 bit version even exists as a portable version

One thing I wanted to change first is the settings to

```
[x] ignore system language
```

because it confused my to have the UI in English but enter decimal digits in German.

Let me give the same examples as I did for Phyxcalc:

```
4m/s*4.3s
=17.2m

2m²+5000cm²
=2.5m²
```

For year, Phyxcalc uses `yr` and Qalculate uses `year`:

```
5W*1year
=157.788 MJ
```

Conversion is possible as well, but not that convenient to type (or I did not yet figure out how to type):

[image: Example of unit conversion]

And an example where the nice output is a bit more obvious (in dark mode):

[image: Example of integration]

Answer (score 4):

I was happy with Phyxcalc for a long time. See [another answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/74745/1935) recommending Qalculate now.

---

I'm happy to have found [Phyxcalc](http://home.arcor.de/cschi/).

- Physxcalc can calculate with units, just type them

  ```
  4m/s*4.3s
  =17.2m

  2m²+5000cm²
  =2.5m²
  ```
- can convert units with the `->` operator

  ```
  5W*1yr
  =157784760J
  5W*1yr->kWh
  =43.8291kWh

  2m²+5000cm²
  =2.5m²
  2m²+5000cm² -> ft²
  =26.9097760417743ft²
  ```
- is gratis ([freeware](http://home.arcor.de/cschi/phyxcalc.html), exact license unknown)
- works on Windows 95, 98, XP, Vista and 7 officially.
- works on Windows 10 (Build 10586) on my VM as well.
- startup time is less than 1 second on my second generation Intel i5
- is portable (single executable + a few text files with unit definitions)
- is easy to use: well, at least kind of. Entering formulas are quite straight forward as seen before. However, it starts with a completely empty UI that does not react on <kbd>F1</kbd>.

  [image: Phyxcalc default UI]

  It is possible to show a keypad using the context menu:

  [image: Phyxcalc key pad]

Comment: It appears to support only German.  Is there any way to change it to English ?

Comment: @RohitGupta: oops. I didn't notice. It seems there's an open source version at https://github.com/strahlex/PhyxCalc I need to have a look at that version.

Answer (score 0):

Not many people seem to be aware, but Windows (10, at least) has some of these functions built in, with its Calculator.

From what I could tell, it doesn't seem to be capable of adding together units natively, but it does have the ability to convert between units, which can assist with calculations at a later stage.

Simply open up Calc(Search in the Start Menu) and click the little burger icon at the top left for many unit options:

[image: Image showing calculator conversion options]

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.12, [Speedcrunch](https://speedcrunch.org/) supports units as well.

- it is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), licensed under GPL
- that can calculate including units (see screenshot below)
- can convert units (see screenshot below)
- works on Windows 10 (I tried, see screenshot below)
- starts up quickly (hardly measureable)
- is also available as a portable version

[image: Screenshot]